# Can't get the editText integer value right

Tags: android

I'm new to programming so i really don't know how to fix this or why it's happening.

I'm making an app and in the Main2Activity it's suppose for the user to insert a value in an EditText and then, after the user presses a button, that value will turn to integer and be used in a mathematical operation.

The thing is, when i try it out, when I press the button in MainActivity to take me to the Main2Activity, the app crashes.

I narrowed the problem to the coding I have in the button from Main2Activity but don't really know what's wrong.

This is the Main2Activity code. Can you help me? Thanks.

```
package com.example.cabr.teste;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public double valorhorasponta = 0;
    public double valorhorascheias = 0;
    public double valorhorasvazio = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        TextView textView9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        TextView textView10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        TextView textView12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
        TextView textView14 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView14);
        final TextView textView11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        final TextView textView13 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);
        final TextView textView15 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView15);
        final TextView textView17 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView17);

        final EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        final EditText editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String valorpot1 = i.getStringExtra("valorpot1");
        String valorpot12 = i.getStringExtra("valorpot12");

        textView9.setText(valorpot1);


        if (valorpot12.equals("Tarifas de médias utilizações")){
            valorhorasponta = 0.3128;
            textView10.setText(String.valueOf(valorhorasponta));

            valorhorascheias = 0.1555;
            textView12.setText(String.valueOf(valorhorascheias));

            valorhorasvazio = 0.0862;
            textView14.setText(String.valueOf(valorhorasvazio));
        }
        if (valorpot12.equals("Tarifas de longas utilizações")){
            valorhorasponta = 0.2318;
            textView10.setText(String.valueOf(valorhorasponta));

            valorhorascheias = 0.1341;
            textView12.setText(String.valueOf(valorhorascheias));

            valorhorasvazio = 0.08;
            textView14.setText(String.valueOf(valorhorasvazio));
        }

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String valorquantponta1 = editText1.getText().toString();
                int valorquantponta = Integer.parseInt(valorquantponta1);

                String valorquantcheias1 = editText2.getText().toString();
                int valorquantcheias = Integer.parseInt(valorquantcheias1);

                String valorquantvazio1 = editText3.getText().toString();
                int valorquantvazio = Integer.parseInt(valorquantvazio1);

                String valorquantpot1 = editText4.getText().toString();
                int valorquantpot = Integer.parseInt(valorquantpot1);

                double valortotponta = valorhorasponta * valorquantponta;
                double valortotcheias = valorhorascheias * valorquantcheias;
                double valortotvazio = valorquantvazio * valorhorasvazio;

                textView11.setText(String.valueOf(valortotponta));
                textView13.setText(String.valueOf(valortotcheias));
                textView15.setText(String.valueOf(valortotvazio));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: We can't do much just with this "the app crashes". Paste the log you are getting please =).

Comment: Please post the log also. My guess would be you need to cast the int to double while multiplying it.

Answer (score 0):

You can take value from EditText in this way

EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

String string=editText.getText().toString;

int int_value_from_editText=Integer.parseInt(string);

Answer (score 0):

You can get `NullPointerException` because `valorpot1` and `valorpot12` could be `null` if an intent doesn't have extras `valorpot1` and `valorpot12`. Comparing null object with some string value will throw an exception. To avoid it:

replace:

```
String valorpot1 = i.getStringExtra("valorpot1");
String valorpot12 = i.getStringExtra("valorpot12");
```

with:

```
String valorpot1 = i.hasExtra("valorpot1") ? i.getStringExtra("valorpot1") : "";
String valorpot12 = i.hasExtra("valorpot12") ? i.getStringExtra("valorpot12") : "";
```

Another possible app crash can be due to improper conversion from String to Integer. Your EditText can contain letters or double value which is not convertible to an integer. Therefore you need to check it before using.

Use `convertToInt` method provided below to convert `String` to `Integer`. Replace `Integer.parseInt`with `convertToInt` in your code.

```
private int convertToInt(String value)
{
    if (value.matches("^-?\\d+$"))
    {
        return Integer.parseInt(value);
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

You can have other exceptions which can lead to the app crash. It would be much helpful if you provide us a [Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html) report.